# Efficient graph reshaping

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a `directed acyclic graph` whose vertices have at most `2` incoming edges. Vertices are divided into levels, that are calculated this way: level of a vertex with no incoming edges is `0`, level of a vertex `v` not belonging to level `0` can be calculated as `max { level(u) + 1 }`, for each `edge (u, v)` belonging to the graph.

I need to reshape the graph so that every level has no more than a set number `k` of vertices ("width"). In most cases `k`  has to be `1024`.

In this [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy2BS.png) the graph has to be shaped for it to have maximum level width `2`. The red node is moved from level `0` to level `1`, causing level `1` width to become `3`, so another upwards movement is required.

Right now I'm calculating the levels for each node in the graph using a slight modification of `Bellman-Ford algorithm` : I add a "source" node connected to all the level `0` nodes (that are known) and run the algorithm picking the maximum distance instead of the minimum distance.

To reshape the graph I'm partitioning the vertices by level, and starting from the level `0`, I'm moving the exceeding vertices upwards. After each move I need to update the level partitioning, since all the subgraph connected to the moved vertex is moved up consequently. This approach was proven to be inefficient for the graphs I'm working on, since I need to move elements up repeatedly, resulting in multiple runs of Bellman-Ford causing a bottleneck.

Here's the code of my reshaping function:

```
void Graph::Reshape(int width) // Width is the maximum width of any level
{

    // Run Bellman-Ford to create the level partitioning in m_levels
    Levelize(); 

    int currentLevel = 0;

    do
    {
        int levelWidth = m_levels[currentLevel].size();

        int widthDifference = levelWidth - width;

        if (widthDifference > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < widthDifference; i++)
            {

                // Get the first vertex in the current level to move it up
                Vertex v = m_levels[currentLevel].front();      

                // Add a vertex f to the graph, between v and all the vertices
                // directly connected to v (resulting in v moving 1 level higher)
                Vertex f = boost::add_vertex(m_graph);

                auto inEdges = boost::in_edges(v, m_graph);

                for (auto it = inEdges.first; it != inEdges.second; it++)
                {
                    Vertex s = boost::source(*it, m_graph);
                    boost::add_edge(s, f, m_graph);
                }

                boost::add_edge(f, v, m_graph);

            }

            // Run Bellman-Ford again to update the level partitioning
            Levelize(); 

        }

    } while (++currentLevel < m_levels.size());

}
```

Is there some clever approach to speed things up?